# How can i repeat a texture at its original scale on my cube in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, repeat, stretch

So as you see in the picture, i made a texture repeat on a rectangle(its size is 40,10,60) but it repeat the same amount of time on every face,so depending of the size of the face the texture is stretched.
In the picture you see that on the top face the texture repeat correctly and keep its original size but on the other faces it is streched.
Is there a way to repeat the texture without changing its size ?
Thank you for your responses.

[screen of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTDpm.png)

Edit : this script in c# does exactly what i want but is there a way to do it without a script since it was done in 2017 ?
https://github.com/Dsphar/Cube_Texture_Auto_Repeat_Unity/blob/master/ReCalcCubeTexture.cs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Depends on your shader I guess ...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will probably need to create a new material with the same image for each different scale using the 'Tiling' attribute:

[image]

*** Edit #1

The x and y Tiling values need to proportional to the scale of the plane or it will stretch.

Comment: Okey thanks for your response david,
i found this script https://github.com/Dsphar/Cube_Texture_Auto_Repeat_Unity/blob/master/ReCalcCubeTexture.cs which does what i want but i was wondering if there is a way to do it without a script now since it was done in 2017

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the mesh being textured is static, you can change its UVs in a 3d program. You could even change the UVs via script.

Another option would be to look into worldspace (triplanar) shaders. These texture based on world position rather than the vertices local position.

If you are using Shader Graph, look at the triplanar node.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Triplanar-Node.html

Comment: Okey thanks ! i'm a begginer so i don't really know what UVs are but i'm going to try this